# OpenCV masking in Java returns empty pixels value

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have created a program in Android that streams from the camera using CvCameraViewListener2. I have completed the image processing I want of getting only the masked image from source image and the binary image with a certain shape. The masking of image is successful but I noticed that when you move along with the camera (the camera is facing me) there seems to be area that is not updating. The only pixels that is updating is the masked image, other pixels parts of the image that is not included in the mask seems to be empty. Is it really empty? Because in Python, areas outside the masked image will be black (0,0,0) value for a 3 channel image.

```
  public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

    // Rotate mRgba 90 degrees
    Core.transpose(mRgba, mRgbaT);
    Imgproc.resize(mRgbaT, mRgbaF, mRgbaF.size(), 0,0, 0);
    Core.flip(mRgbaF, mRgba, 1 );

    // Read the current frames.
    // All the rest of the code is patterned just like OpenCV in Python.
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, imgOrig, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(imgOrig, imgOrigBGR, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(imgOrigBGR, imgLAB, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2Lab);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(imgOrigBGR, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(gray, blurred,new Size(5,5),0);
    Imgproc.threshold(blurred,binarized,threshold,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    //Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(blurred, binarized,255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV,5,1);

    // Mask the lab space image using the binary image that is adjustable from the seekbar.
    // **Based from the output, the masked image contains empty values from Mat and only contains the pixels of the masked
    // image itself.
    Core.bitwise_and(imgLAB,imgLAB,masked,binarized);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mat object does not delete its previous contents that is why when you assign a new value to the Mat, the values that are not affected by the new image data are retained because using mask (bitwise and) will only return the values are in the mask. To solve this, you create a new instance of the Mat object before doing some masking to delete its previous contents unlike in Python OpenCV which automatically makes pixels not affected by the mask be black.